# video.js scub bar not working?

Tags: django, video.js

I'm using source files as is from video.js.
I'm loading the below code into a `tab-pane active`.

The video `play` button works.
The `scrub` bar doesn't work.  Only tested thus far in chrome.

**UPDATE 1**

`<div class="span9">
    <video id="tutorial_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto" poster="{{STATIC_URL}}video/tutorial/first-frame-how-to-guide.png">
    <source src="{{STATIC_URL}}video/tutorial/tutorial.mp4" type='video/mp4'> 
    <source src="{{STATIC_URL}}video/tutorial/tutorial.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</div>`

Here is the style code that I used to position the movie in the middle.

`.video-js .vjs-tech {
    position: relative !important;
}`

Here is a gif of it not working.

[image]

I do not get any introspector errors or console errors.

**UPDATE 2**

I broke out the code. 
It worked.
I overwrote the video-js files with fresh ones from above it worked. 
I changed a chunk of `video-js.css` to below.  It didn't work.
I changed it back, cleared my cache and refreshed the page.  It didn't work.

```
/* Individual tracks */
.video-js .vjs-text-track {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  /* Transparent black background, or fallback to all black (oldIE) */
  /* background-color-with-alpha */
  background-color: #00618e;
  background-color: rgba(0, 97, 142, 1);
}
.video-js .vjs-subtitles {
  color: #ffffff /* Subtitles are white */;
}
.video-js .vjs-captions {
  color: #ffffff /* Captions are yellow */;
}
.vjs-tt-cue {
  display: block;
}
```

I noticed this error message in the django web server log.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.70', 54466)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 126
  , in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
    error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I belive that the issue may be with DJANGO's test server.  I don't belive this to be an actual issue with `video-js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this error message in the django web server log.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.70', 54466)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 126
  , in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
    error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I belive that the issue may be with DJANGO's test server.  I don't belive this to be an actual issue with `video-js`.

Comment: Did you have any solution with this issue

Answer (score 0):

It should not work. Django should not "handle" videos or other static files. Is is job ob Web Servers (nginx, apache, ....). Django will only give url to static file and Web Server will process it. 
When you deploy your application you will catch /static/ or /media/ urls requests with Web Server.

For nginx as an example we have [this](http://nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/).

Comment: The video does play -- but your saying it can't scrub because it's just sending the entire file and not streaming it?   I'm planning on hosting the video on amazon-cloudfront will that video the streaming issues if it's hosted as RMTP stream?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not work with amazon-cloudfront, but I am sure that they have streaming feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive that this will fix your issue completely, but your video.js embed code is a little messed up. You have two video tags, and one is inside the fallback paragraph ("vjs-no-video") with no sources. Compare it to the embed code on videojs.com.

```
<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, posting a live example or any errors that show up in the browser error console will help debug the issue.

Comment: I added a gif showing the issue and updated the code.  Is user2309693 correct in the fact I need to host the file in a non-django setup?

Comment: If the video is playing, then it's not a streaming issue. There's some other problem happening with the controls there, and I can't tell what it is. You should check the javascript error console for any errors that might be happening. And also remove other scripts on the page to see if they're creating conflicts.